# Fluentd + Elasticsearch = Connection refused

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

I'm trying to connect fluentd with elasticsearch and I'm getting this error when I start the td-agent service.

td-agent.log:

**Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:9092 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)**

td-agent.conf

```
<match docker.*>
  @type elasticsearch
  host localhost
  port 9092
  logstash_format true
</match>
```

My elasticsearch is running because I can check on `http://localhost:9200/` and also the fluentd plugin

```
plugin 2020-05-21 12:57:55 -0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-elasticsearch' version '4.0.8'
```

Comment: I was using the wrong port on .conf :(. The right is 9200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access elasticsearch from `localhost:9200` then the `.conf` will look like:

```
<match docker.*>
  @type elasticsearch
  host localhost
  port 9200
  logstash_format true
</match>
```